# filters based on multiple button selection

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I am new to front end and I am trying to create a project. As per required design, I have five buttons. Four buttons indicate different states(error, expired, risk, ok) and fifth button indicates the total of all four. Right now the buttons act as toggle.

I want to implement filters based on multiple selection among four buttons or single selection of 'Total'. For example, if I click on 'error' and 'risk',I should be able to apply some css to indicate multiple selection and I want to pass this as comma separated filters(error, risk) to back end API. I should be able to unselect the buttons after clicking again. Also when I click on all, all the other buttons(error, risk in this example) should be unselected. Can someone please point me in right direction of how to achieve that.

template code

```
<div class="top-row">
  <div class="total" (click)="onClick('TOTAL')" [ngClass]="{'selected': eventState === 'TOTAL'}">
        <div>{{ total }}</div>
       <div>
         Total
       </div> 
   </div>
   <div class="states">
      <button (click)="onClick('ERROR')" [ngClass]="{'selected': state === 'ERROR'}">
          <div>{{ error }}</div>
          <div>Error</div>
      </button>
     <button (click)="onClick('EXPIRED')" [ngClass]="{'selected': state === 'EXPIRED'}">
         <div>{{ expired }}</div>
           Expired
       </button>

     <button (click)="onClick('RISK')" [ngClass]="{'selected': state === 'RISK'}">
         <div>{{ risk }}</div>
         <div>&nbsp;Risk</div>
     </button>
     <button (click)="onClick('OK')" [ngClass]="{'selected': state === 'OK'}">
         <div>{{ ok }}</div>
         <div>&nbsp;Ok</div>
     </button>
   </div> 
</div>
```

Here is the CSS file

```
.top-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

    .selected { 
        background-color: rgba(189,218,241,.35);
    }    

    .total{
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        width: 100px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 30px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-family: Roboto-Medium,sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #004677;
        div:first-child{
            font-size: 20px;
        }
    }

    .states {
        background-color: white;
        flex-grow: 1;
        border-left: 1px solid black;
        padding-left: 10px;

        button {
            margin-right: 10px;
            width: 100px;
        }

        button div {
            line-height: 30px;
        }

        button div:first-child {
            font-size: 20px;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're asking for quit a bit without providing the component dealing with what you already have. Looks to me, based on checking on a single state, it would require quite a bit of rewriting. Maybe get it to where you can have multiple states/buttons selected  so the question is about implementing the "all" part. Side note: have you considered using a multi select with check boxes?

Comment: Yes, but I want to implement it with buttons instead of multi select check boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement component logic by using **`push()`** and **`splice()`** JavaScript Array functions on some conditions as follows.

```
  states = { ERROR: 'ERROR', EXPIRED: 'EXPIRED', RISK: 'RISK', OK: 'OK', TOTAL: 'TOTAL' };
  selectedStates: string[] = [];

  constructor() {}

  onClick(type: string): void {

    // If clicked states not equal to TOTAL
    if (type !== this.states.TOTAL) {

          // Add/Remove states besides TOTAL
          const index = this.selectedStates.indexOf(type);
          if (index === -1) {
            this.selectedStates.push(type);
          } else {
            this.selectedStates.splice(index, 1);
          }
          // Remove TOTAL if exists
          const totIndex = this.selectedStates.indexOf(this.states.TOTAL);
          if (totIndex > -1) {
            this.selectedStates.splice(totIndex, 1);
          }

    } 
    // If clicked states equal to TOTAL
    else {

      const index = this.selectedStates.indexOf(this.states.TOTAL);
      if (index > -1) {

        this.selectedStates.splice(index, 1);
      } else {

        this.selectedStates = [];
        this.selectedStates.push(type);
      }
    }
  } 

  send(): void {
    console.log(this.selectedStates);
  }
```

Use **`includes()`** Array function to set **`ngClass`** in html as follows.

```
<div class="top-row">
  <div class="total" (click)="onClick(states.TOTAL)" [ngClass]="{'selected': selectedStates.includes(states.TOTAL)}">
        <div>{{ total }}</div>
       <div>
         Total
       </div> 
   </div>
   <div class="states">
      <button (click)="onClick(states.ERROR)" [ngClass]="{'selected': selectedStates.includes(states.ERROR)}">
          <div>{{ error }}</div>
          <div>Error</div>
      </button>
     <button (click)="onClick(states.EXPIRED)" [ngClass]="{'selected': selectedStates.includes(states.EXPIRED)}">
         <div>{{ expired }}</div>
           Expired
       </button>

     <button (click)="onClick(states.RISK)" [ngClass]="{'selected': selectedStates.includes(states.RISK)}">
         <div>{{ risk }}</div>
         <div>&nbsp;Risk</div>
     </button>
     <button (click)="onClick(states.OK)" [ngClass]="{'selected': selectedStates.includes(states.OK)}">
         <div>{{ ok }}</div>
         <div>&nbsp;Ok</div>
     </button>
   </div> 
</div>
```

I did one change in CSS. place **`.selected`** class outside of all other classes.

```
.top-row {
    ...
} 
.selected { 
    background-color: rgba(189,218,241,.35);
}
```

**Find Working [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-57103927?file=src/app/app.component.ts).**

Comment: Thanks and much appreciated! :)